# Syntax error for printing an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm attempting to print an array of php elements embedded in html

If I input

```
echo '<strong>'.$s[firstname].' '.$s[lastname].'</strong><div class="moreinfo"><p><small>'.$s[role].' of '.$parent'.</small></p></div></li>';
```

I get a result that says something like "Chris James Parent of Array

but if I attempt to print the array with a foreach as so

```
echo '<strong>'.$s[firstname].' '.$s[lastname].'</strong><div class="moreinfo"><p><small>'.$s[role].' of '.
            foreach($parent as $p){
                echo $p.' ';
            }
            .'</small></p></div></li>';
```

The program crashes completely. I would assume that I'm doing something syntactically incorrect, but I can't spot the issue. Is there a simply way to print the elements in thearray that would avoid the crash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use debug($s) in your array to see how structured are.
When you see white screen, probably syntax error.

Comment: Could you clarify? I didn't understand your statement

Comment: When you see "Array" printed, it means you have an array and cannot printed without index value.

Try to add this in your code before the foreach statement:

debug($parent);

This function will show you values inside $parent variable structured.

Comment: Unless `firstname` and `lastname` are defined constants, then they should be quoted in `$s['firstname']` and `$s['lastname']`

Answer (score 2):

You concatenate output with `.` not additional PHP statements:

```
echo '<strong>'.$s[firstname].' '.$s[lastname].'</strong><div class="moreinfo"><p><small>'.$s[role].' of ';

            foreach($parent as $p){
                echo $p.' ';
            }

echo '</small></p></div></li>';
```

However you can just implode `$parent`:

```
echo '<strong>'.$s[firstname].' '.$s[lastname].'</strong><div class="moreinfo"><p><small>'.$s[role].' of '.implode(' ', $parent).'.</small></p></div></li>';
```

Comment: This fixed it right up.
I think at this point I just need some sleep.

Thanks for your help!